# SDL Tridion workflow next activity link

Tags: workflow, tridion

I'm having use case which I needs to send mail to User/Group, so that on directly on clicking on this User can finish an Activity. Kindly provide me the URL which I can use by adding my activity tcmCRI to finish the activity.

Answer (score 1):

What is the use case for this? This is going against Workflow idea. User that is finishing activity is supposed to at least look at item before finishing activity. By finishing activity he is taking responsibility to approve item or claim that he performed some actions on it and you want to give user possibility to approve something without even looking at it? The closest you can get to it is to create event handler for OnActivityFinish event or autmatic activity that will send email to user or group when activity get's assigned to him. In this letter you can have link to user work items in CME, where user will see that what is assigned to him and decide what he should do.

Finishing activity is more then just 1 action. User may need to select next activty, or may want to leave message or reassign activity. If you really want to you can create a webservice that will provide these kind of functionality